# Where do I download a Java 6 JDK for Linux?

Tags: linux, sdk, java

May be I am getting old, but I can't find it...

Comment: The first google hit for "Java 6 JDK for Linux" is the download page. Surely you're not too old to use google?

Comment: You should not download packages on your own, you need to install packages provided by your distribution.

Comment: Rubbish. Absolutely nothing wrong with downloading them yourself, especially considering the linux package repos are usually miles behind current releases.

Comment: @skaffman is it also a case with jdk too?

Comment: downloading java directly from oracle makes sense in many situations, put them in /usr/local somewhere and update PATH and JAVA_HOME accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

linux package manager (which ever you are using). It will save you a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 0):

It is never so easy to find what you want at that site, but luckily today I have found it ;).

https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=jdk-6u14-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer

Answer (score 0):

http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/?intcmp=1281

https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewFilteredProducts-SingleVariationTypeFilter